# divergence of $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n}+2}{n-2}$ verification/ alternative method

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I wish to prove divergence of 
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n}+2}{n-2}$$

I wish to do so by comparison, since $n\geq 3$:
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n}+2}{n-2} > \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1+2}{n-2}>\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{3}{n}>\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow \infty$$
And the harmonic series is divergent, so if we just remove finitely many terms, we still have that it is divergent, because divergence is determined "in the tail". We have a divergent minorant series and hence the original series diverges to $\infty$.

Is this approach fine, or is there some more elegant method, this was about the simplest thing I could think of.

---

Alternatively we have: 
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n}+2}{n-2} > \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n}+2}{n}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+ \frac{2}{n}\rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The summand is $O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$, which diverges

Comment: My bad. I had the question in my head but did not actually write it out xD

Comment: Apparently $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges, I was not sure about this, but with that method I could just carry out the division and conclude this immediately I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what your question is, but your answer is correct.

Your approach is fine. Comparison test would be the proper test to use.

One can also show that $$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty \:}\frac{\sqrt{n}+2}{n-2}\ge \sum _{n=3}^{\infty \:}\frac{\sqrt{n}+2}{n}$$

and show that the rightmost sum is diverging via the integral test.

Comment: That's a nice alternative, we haven't practised a lot with this yet, but this method would work very well :)

Comment: Right now I am still trying to figure out which method would be best suited for which situation, I still feel I'm just throwing all I know at a question most of the time - but I'm getting better.

Comment: Generally if you can't evaluate it directly, but you can "visualize" the series diverges, then this test is good.

Comment: Intuiton can be developed, you're right ;) "seeing it" and a proof are sometimes closer than it seems.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n}+2}{n-2}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{n}-2}$$ and the terms are of order $n^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}+2}{n-2} \sim \frac {\sqrt n}n=\frac1{\sqrt n}$$

the series diverges by [**limit comparison test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum \frac1{\sqrt n}$.